# Issue with styling paragraph tags in nested components

Tags: html, css

I have trouble to style paragraph tags in nested components in PostCss+ReactJs app.
First I was thinking I miss something in PostCss and how it works with react component but later tried to reproduce the issue with plain CSS and HTML and have same misbehavior.

- HTML

```
<div class="parentPar">
      <p>Parent Paragraph 1</p>
      <p class="hd">SubHeader paragraph</p>
      <p >Normal paragraph</p>
</div>
```

- CSS

```
div.parentPar p{
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.hd{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

p{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

If you remove `class="parentPar"` from topmost `div` browser would render `SubHeader paragraph` in red and all others in blue
But with `class="parentPar"` in topmost `div` browser would render all paragraphs in green. Does this mean that parent container suppress styles in child?

Here is codepen to play https://codepen.io/javapantry/pen/LYGwbeP

Comment: "app" is defined as an id in your html and as a class in the css, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I left this unrelated to problem div by mistake. It's not related. I've update post and codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the css I indicated where I changed

```css
.parentPar > p{ /* this it */
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/*div.app p{
    color: lime;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 550;
}*/

.hd{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

p{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentPar">
    <p>Parent Paragraph 1</p>
    <div id="app">
      <p class="hd">SubHeader paragraph</p>
      <p>Normal paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand syntax `.parentPar > p`. Thank you.

Comment: referring to a direct descendant.

Comment: `.parentPar p` - this way you will assign rules to all child `p` inside the `.parentPar` class

Answer (score 1):

`app` is not a class. It's an `id` so this line in your css:

```
div.app p{
```

can be changed to:

```
#app p{
```

Then `.hd{` gets changed to `#app p.hd` so as to be more specific.

And finally, I added a class to the last `<p>` element to keep it simple `#app p.newClass`
as shown in the snippet below:
This one is all about specificty.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

```css
div.parentPar p {
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#app p {
  color: lime;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

#app p.hd {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#app p.newClass {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentPar">
  <p>Parent Paragraph 1</p>
  <div id="app">
    <p class="hd">SubHeader paragraph</p>
    <p class="newClass">Normal paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's related to specificity, because you are using classes in both cases but one of them also has a cascade, so it prevails. If you use an id instead of class for the subheader, it does not happen:

```
<div class="parentPar">
  <p>Parent Paragraph 1</p>
  <p id="hd">SubHeader paragraph</p>
  <p >Normal paragraph</p>
</div>

CSS:

#hd{
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've put `p` selector at the end of your stylesheet so it will overwrite all other styles that have been applied to any `p` tag, also there are no `app` classes in your HTML code, so the applied styles of `.app` selector won't show anywhere but there is a `#app` selector.

so :

```
p{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
div .parentPar p{
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

div #app p{
    color: lime;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 550;
}

.hd{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```